# Free dataset of world cities, including geometry

Tags: data, geometry, city

I am looking for a free dataset of world cities. I checked all the datasets suggested in the question: [Seeking Country/State/City Database?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/603/is-a-country-state-city-database-available), but couldn't find one where the city location is available as a polygon (or similar), I found only latitude/longitude.

Actually, I don't even need a very precise polygon, the end use is just to compute if a given point is in a city or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're really talking about cities down to 500-1000 inhabitants, you can't even get that data if you pay for it. Even the *locations* of cities with 1000 people are something that's hard to pay for -- there's a *lot* of cities of that size in the world.

Commercial providers like NAVTEQ don't tend to have polygons for anything that small, for example, because it can't be collected via on-the-ground data.

If you limited yourself to looking for rough outlines of cities of 1 *million* people or more, VMap0 might have the data you're looking for -- but it's very coarse.

If you don't care about 'free as in freedom' but instead only free as in "I don't have to pay for it", you might try [Reverse Geocoding](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding); use a reverse geocoder to look up a location, and then look at the city field. This is probably your best bet -- but ties you to someone who has a good geocoder that they make available (Google) and all that that entails.

Answer (score 1):

Geonames WebServices may be a fit (http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html). You can search by lat lon, or download the entire data set to slice and dice it how you need.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can download a shapefile with polygons for about 6,000 world cities: https://geo.nyu.edu/catalog/stanford-yk247bg4748