# Global address datasets for testing?

Tags: data, geocoding

Are there any free global address datasets I can use to test my geocoding application?  I'm looking for a dataset that contains residential addresses from countries around the world.  I don't need a name, just a street address, region, country, and postal code (if the country uses postal codes).  If it has a latitude and longitude for each address, that would be a plus.

I saw this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20294/free-dataset-of-world-cities-including-city-geometry) but I'm wondering if anything has changed since it was answered.

Thanks.

Comment: Try [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12289222/generate-real-us-street-addresses-for-selenium-rc-script/12289780#12289780), maybe? (Works only for US addresses but you might try a similar approach for different countries.)